# Argument 1 passed to Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart::search() laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cart

Frontend:

```
<form action="update_cart/{{$value->id}}/update" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" /> 
    <input type="number" name="update_qty" value="{{$value->qty}}"/>        
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function update_cart( $id,$method ){
   if ($method=='update') {
        $rowId = Cart::search(array('id' => $id));
        $item = Cart::get($rowId[0]);
        $update_qty = Requests::input('update_qty');
        Cart::update($rowId[0], $update_qty);
       return back();
   }
}
```

I get this error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
> Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart::search() must be an instance of Closure,
> array given, called in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomerce\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php
> on line 221

Comment: Show us your routes file

Comment: Route::post('/update_cart/{id}/{method}', 'frontend@update_cart');

Answer (score 0):

```
Argument passed to ..::search() must be an instance of Closure, array given
```

As the error message says, you should not send an array to the `search` method but a Closure:

```
$item = Cart::search(function ($cart, $key) use($id) {
   return $cart->id == $id;
})->first();
```

It should directly return the item, not only the id. 
If you want a reference, the `search` methods only use your Closure to filter your collection of Cart, as described [here, search for filter() method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections)